# Dash Loading children - Persistance of content after page refresh

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following Dash application, in which a callback function has some logic triggered by a button, that update the content of an html.Div component (id="run-button-feedback") and refresh the page. However, I am unable to avoid that the html.Div component return to its inital value after a page refresh.

The page refresh is essential for other components to update, however this html.Div component need to contain a message to user that persists after page refresh

How can I make this happen?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.GRID])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
server = app.server

app.layout = dbc.Container([
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False, href='home/page/'),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                html.Span(
                    "RUN",
                    id="run-button",
                    n_clicks=0,
                    className="button",
                ),
            ]),
            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Loading(
                    id="run-button-loading",
                    children=[
                        html.Div(id="run-button-feedback")
                    ],
                    type="circle",
                ),
            ])
        ]),
    ], style={"margin": "0%"}, fluid=True)  # fluid=True for Container to fill horizontal space and resize fluidly


# callback logic
@app.callback(
                [Output('url', 'pathname'),
                 Output('run-button-feedback', 'children')],
                [Input('run-button', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('url', 'pathname')],
             )
def refresh_analysis(n_clicks, url):
    """
    Refresh page on which it was called
    """
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return url, "message that need to persist after page refresh <p>clicked {} times</p>".format(n_clicks)
    return url, "Initial value"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `dcc.Store`:

> The store component can be used to keep data in the visitor's browser. The data is scoped to the user accessing the page.
>
> Three types of storage (storage_type prop):
>
> memory: default, keep the data as long the page is not refreshed.
>
> local: keep the data until it is manually cleared.
>
> session: keep the data until the browser/tab closes.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components#store

So you could put this in your layout for example:

```
dcc.Store(id="store", storage_type='session')
```

And have two callbacks like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('url', 'pathname'),
    Output('store', 'data'),
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('url', 'pathname'),
    State('store', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def refresh_analysis(n_clicks, url, store):
    """
    Refresh page on which it was called
    """
    if store:
        return url, {"message": f"message that need to persist after page refresh <p>clicked {store['n_clicks'] + 1} times</p>", "n_clicks": store['n_clicks'] + 1}
    elif n_clicks > 0:
        return url, {"message": f"message that need to persist after page refresh <p>clicked {n_clicks} times</p>", "n_clicks": n_clicks}
    return url, {"message": "Initial value", "n_clicks": n_clicks}


@app.callback(
    Output('run-button-feedback', 'children'),
    Input('store', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def refresh_analysis(store_data):
    if store_data:
        return store_data["message"]
```

The idea is that we first store the message and the number of clicks in our store component. When the `data` attribute of the store component updates we update the text to display on the page in another callback.